# Where are the brachot written down?

Tags: blessing

I hope this isn't an ignorant question, but I wonder if there is one place that all the b'rachot are written down, and if so, where is it? Are they all in the Mishnah?

Comment: Hello Tanya and welcome to Mi Yodeya.  Thank you for bringing your question here (which is definitely not ignorant!).  Are you looking for a common *source* for the brachot, or a *practical compilation* (what to say when)?

Comment: Most of them are in a Siddur.

Comment: http://www.nehora.com/birkhoth-eliyahu-guide-laws-of-blessing/

Answer (score 1):

They are written down several places, along with their various rules.  The source for them (as well as reference to the various sources) is the sixth chapter (Keitzad Mevarchin) of the [Gemmarra Tractate Berakhot, starting on page 35a](http://www.dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=brachos&daf=35a).
The Ayin Mishpat Ner Mitzvah section of the page (found in the upper corner of the outer margin) will tell you where to locate the halakhot discussed on each page in the appropriate Jewish legal codes (which will also there have the Berakhot and their rules).

Comment: I haven't ever learned _Ketzad M'var'chin_, and am astounded to learn that every single _b'racha_ is sourced there.

Comment: When you say the sources and references are in the 6th Perek, do you mean to say the Perek tells us the sources, or that the Perek is the (written) source?

Comment: There are many blessings not sourced in the 6th chapter of Tractate Brachot, or even in Tractate Brachot at all.

Answer (score 1):

In the book 'Birkhoth Eliyahu' the English version You will find all of them in Hebrew and English with transliteration. You can find there all the types of food + photos with their blessings

Comment: Hi Avi, welcome to mi yodeya, thanks for this answer. could you provide a link to the work you cite?